# Windows update caused a connection problem with SSMS to my server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I installed a windows update on Windows 10 and now SQL Server Management Studio cannot connect to my server instance. On the server, TLS 1.0 was disabled over a year ago. I have been able to connect everyday up until the windows update. My other co-workers are able to connect just fine. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 on both the client and the server.

Here is the exact error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893007)

Current server registry values:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client]
> "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
> "Enabled"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
> "Enabled"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
> "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
> "Enabled"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
> "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
> "Enabled"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
> "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
> "Enabled"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
> "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
> "Enabled"=dword:00000001

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Mayhap the real solution is use a supported version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Larnu Yes I understand it's now unsupported, however upgrading at the moment is not an option

Comment: What are the values in the registry keys `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client` and `TLS 1.0\Client` on your PC? Does the server have TLS 1.2 enable per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe ?

Comment: @Charlieface I've updated my post to include server registry values. I'm a little confused by that KB what protocol(s) I should be using and which one ssms is trying to use

Comment: That KB tells you which patch is needed for TLS 1.2, depending on which version of SQL Server you have. It seems somehow TLS 1.1 is disabled on your side, even though your registry indicates it is still enabled. But you should try to get the correct patch in place ASAP in order to use 1.2 as 1.1 is insecure.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to correct my issue by upgrading Sql Server 2008 r2 to SP3 and then I applied this patch: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sql-server-2008-r2-sp3-gdr-january-6-2018-f8290bc2-5abe-934c-4672-c454db0b73f6

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when connecting from Windows Server 2012.
I resolved by changing the TLS and SSL settings using the IIS Crypto executable. Specifically, I disabled Server Protocols SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0. I also disabled Client Protocol SSL 3.0 (I believe this is what did the trick)
[image: Screenshot - IIS Crypto Settings]